# Not getting the final output in the python program for web dev

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2, google-app-engine-python

I wrote the following code for printing the rot13 code for a string. Rot13 code is where you shift the letters of the string by 13 places. But for some reason, the textbox printed is always blank. Can someone please help me with this code?

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
import cgi
import string

template_dir= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env= jinja2.Environment(loader= jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),
                                                                         autoescape= True) # automatically escapes all the variables


form="""
<form method="post">
      <textarea name="text" style="height: 100px; width: 400px;">%(val)s</textarea>
      <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
"""

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def write(self,*a,**kw):
        self.response.out.write(*a,**kw)

    def render_str(self,template,**params):
        #Causes Jinja to load that file creating jinja template
        t=jinja_env.get_template(template)
        return t.render(params)

    def render(self,template,**kw):
        self.write(self.render_str(template,**kw))



class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def escape_html(self,s):
        return cgi.escape(s, quote=True)

    def write_form(self, s=''):
        self.response.out.write(form % {"val":s})

    def get(self):
        self.write_form()

    def rot13(self, s):
        out=""
        str1 =  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
        str2 = "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"
        for c in s:
            if c in str1:
                k = str1.index(c)
                out += string.replace( s,c, str2[k])
            else:
                out += c
        return out

    def post(self):
        user_text = self.request.get('text')
        user_text = self.escape_html(user_text)
        user_text = self.rot13(user_text)


        self.write_form(user_text)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage)
], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
import codecs
```

and then into the POST you can convert directly the string to rot_13 using:

```
text = codecs.encode(user_text, 'rot_13')
```

Here the the code modified:

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2
import cgi
import string
import codecs

template_dir= os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates')
jinja_env= jinja2.Environment(loader= 
jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir),

autoescape= True) # automatically escapes all the variables


form="""
<form method="post">
  <textarea name="text" style="height: 100px; width: 400px;">%
  (val)s</textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
"""

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
   def write(self,*a,**kw):
      self.response.out.write(*a,**kw)

   def render_str(self,template,**params):
      #Causes Jinja to load that file creating jinja template
      t=jinja_env.get_template(template)
      return t.render(params)

   def render(self,template,**kw):
      self.write(self.render_str(template,**kw))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def escape_html(self,s):
        return cgi.escape(s, quote=True)

    def write_form(self, s=''):
        self.response.out.write(form % {"val":s})

    def get(self):
       self.write_form()

def post(self):
    user_text = self.request.get('text')
    text = codecs.encode(user_text, 'rot_13')
    self.write_form(text)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage)
], debug=True)
```

Here the result animation with the app working:

[image]

Edits:
If you wants use your routine:

```
def rot13(self, s):
    out = ""
    str1 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    str2 = "NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm"
    for c in s:
        if c in str1:
            k = str1.index(c)
            #out += string.replace(s, c, str2[k])
            out += str2[k]
        else:
            out += c
    return out
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This did the work for me. But I couldn't understand what was wrong with my code. Can you please help me with that too?

Comment: sure @Taylor if you want use your routine the problem is into   out += string.replace(s, c, str2[k]). You need should only concatenate the conversion out += str2[k]. If you want I can add the modification into the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Nicolas ! This indeed was very helpful!

Comment: Great @Taylor happy to heard that!

Comment: @Taylor if was useful the contribution please vote the post. You have 2 options positive or negative :)